# Spark Dataframe complex ordering

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a event log dataset, like this:

```
| patient | timestamp     | event_st       | extra_info |
| 1       | 1/1/2018 2:30 | urg_admission  | x          |
| 1       | 1/1/2018 3:00 | urg_discharge  | x          |
| 1       | 1/1/2018      | hosp_admission | y          |
| 1       | 1/10/2018     | hosp_discharge | y          |
```

I want to order all rows by `patient` and `timestamp`, but unfortunately, depending on the type of event `event_st`, the `timestamp` may be in minutes or days granularity.

So, the solution I would use in C++ would be define a complex `<` operator, where I would use the `event_st` as a discriminator when time granularity differs. For example, with the shown data, the events with `hosp_` prefix will be always ordered after the events with `urg_` prefix, when their day are the same.

Is there any equivalent approach using the `DataFrame` API or other Spark APIs?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In this case, wouldn't it be possible to order the data by 3 columns then? First on `patient` then on `event_st` and finally on the timestamp? Or do you have more event types? (in that case you can consider adding a new column with two values to order by instead of `event_st`).

Comment: Hi @Shaido. Thanks for your comment. I added an `event_order` numerical column which is  a recoding of the `event_st`, where I force a semantic order, and then I set the three-column order you suggested. It seems to work, but I have the feeling that this is a partial solution...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to first normalize all the timestamp to some standard form like ddMMYY or in epoch. The simplest way is to use an udf.

For example: If you consider all the timestamp to be converted to epoch then your code would look like:

```
def convertTimestamp(timeStamp:String, event_st:String) : Long = {
    if(event_st == 'urg_admission') {
    ...// Add conversion logic
    }
    if(event_st == 'hosp_admission') {
    ...// Add conversion logic
    }
     ...
}

val df = spark.read.json("/path/to/log/dataset") // I am assuming json format
spark.register.udf("convertTimestamp", convertTimestamp _)
df.createOrReplaceTempTable("logdataset")
val df_normalized = spark.sql("select logdataset.*, convertTimestamp(timestamp,event_st) as normalized_timestamp from logdataset")
```

After this you can use the normalized dataset form subsequent operation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the comparison is a little bit more complex, because the time granularity is variable: `hosp` events have day granularity and `urg` events have minute granularity. I know that, if the events occur the same day, `hosp` events should be ordered after `urg` events, so the requirement of a complex comparison.